# Hex to 7 Segment Encoder Syntax Errors with When Statments

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to create a hex to 7 segment encoder. When I synthesize I get errors on each line where I have a when statement and I can't figure out why. If anyone can point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it!

```
architecture Behavioral of encoder is
begin
CASE hex IS
  WHEN "0000" =>
    a <= '1';
    b <= '1';
    c <= '1';
    d <= '1';
    e <= '1';
    f <= '1';
    g <= '0';
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a case stucture outside of a process.

If you want a case stucture you would write:

```
process (hex)
begin
  CASE hex IS
    WHEN "0000" =>
      a <= '1';
      b <= '1';
      c <= '1';
      d <= '1';
      e <= '1';
      f <= '1';
      g <= '0';
    WHEN ...
    WHEN ...
    WHEN others =>
      a <= '0'
      b <= '0'
      etc...
end process
```

Alternatively you could use a when/else outside of a process. But you would then probably assign the values to a vector, and split it up afterwards, something like this:

in the architecture:

```
signal sevseg : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0)
```

and in the rtl part:

```
bcd <= "0000000" when hex = "0000" else
       "0011010" when hex = "0001" else
       ...
       "0011110" when hex = "0010" else
       "0000000"

a <= sevseg(0)
b <= sevseg(1)
c <= sevseg(2)
d <= sevseg(2)
...
```

Another option outside of a process is the with/select statement:

```
with hex select sevseg <=
  "0000000" when "0000",
  "0001010" when "0001",
  ...
```

You would then again need to split up bcd into a, b, c, etc. As shown in the previous example.

Comment: `bcd[0]` should be `bcd(0)`, etc

Comment: +1, I wouldn't name the result `bcd` because 7-segment display encoding is not a bcd-encoding (binary coded decimal).

Comment: @Paebbels you're completely right, I've updated the name of the signal

Answer (score 1):

For completeness in addition to anderswb answer:

There's also declaring a subprogram, in this case a function and shown here as an entity declarative item where is can be used by any of that entity's architectures:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity hex_7seg is
    port ( 
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        val:        in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        anode:      out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        segment:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0)
    );

    --  seven segment display
    --  
    --        a
    --     f      b
    --        g
    --     e      c
    --        d
    --
    --  SEGMENT is defined (g downto a)
    --
   function HEX_TO_7SEG (bcd: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0))
       return std_logic_vector is
   begin
       case bcd is
           when "0000" => return "1000000"; -- 0
           when "0001" => return "1111001"; -- 1
           when "0010" => return "0100100"; -- 2
           when "0011" => return "0110000"; -- 3
           when "0100" => return "0011001"; -- 4
           when "0101" => return "0010010"; -- 5
           when "0110" => return "0000010"; -- 6
           when "0111" => return "1111000"; -- 7
           when "1000" => return "0000000"; -- 8
           when "1001" => return "0011000"; -- 9
           when "1010" => return "0001000"; -- A
           when "1011" => return "0000011"; -- b
           when "1100" => return "0111001"; -- C
           when "1101" => return "0100001"; -- d
           when "1110" => return "0000110"; -- E
           when "1111" => return "0001110"; -- F
           when others => return "XXXXXXX"; -- does not synthesize
       end case;
   end function;
end entity;
```

There's also using a ROM with the hex value as an index:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity hex_7seg is
    port ( 
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        val:        in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
        anode:      out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        segment:    out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0)
    );

    --  seven segment display
    --  
    --        a
    --     f      b
    --        g
    --     e      c
    --        d
    --
    --  SEGMENT is defined (g downto a)
    --
    type segment7 is array (integer range 0 to 15) of 
                    std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);

    constant hex_to_segment: segment7 := (
                 "1000000", -- 0
                 "1111001", -- 1
                 "0100100", -- 2
                 "0110000", -- 3
                 "0011001", -- 4
                 "0010010", -- 5
                 "0000010", -- 6
                 "1111000", -- 7
                 "0000000", -- 8
                 "0011000", -- 9
                 "0001000", -- A
                 "0000011", -- b
                 "0111001", -- C
                 "0100001", -- d
                 "0000110", -- E
                 "0001110"  -- F
             );
end entity;

architecture foo of hex_7seg is
    signal seg7_val: integer range 0 to 15;
    signal hex:      std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
    seg7_val <= to_integer(unsigned(hex));

    segment <= hex_to_segment(seg7_val);
end architecture;
```

Note that a function call is an expression as is an indexed array value, meaning they can be used in concurrent or sequential statements.

If you analyze, elaborate and run the above entity/architecture pair you'd find that you get a report statement from to_integer in package numeric_std `metavalue detected, returning 0` because `hex` is  initialized to all X's. When using conversion routines between array types and numeric scalar types care in providing default values when declaring intermediate signals or variables can prevent this.