# i have a vhdl code that take a 16 bit binary converts it to 5 bcd(4bit) how can i connect each bcd with a display?

Tags: vhdl

i have a code that take a 16 bit binary converts it to 5 bcd(4bit)
how can i connect each bcd with a display?
the bcd 0 has to connect to the display 0 (seven segment display) so that the binary number is going to convert to decimal and display it on 5 seven segment displays

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity binary_bcd is
    generic(N: positive := 16);
    port(
        clk, reset: in std_logic;
        binary_in: in std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
        bcd0, bcd1, bcd2, bcd3, bcd4: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end binary_bcd ;

architecture behaviour of binary_bcd is
    type states is (start, shift, done);
    signal state, state_next: states;

    signal binary, binary_next: std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
    signal bcds, bcds_reg, bcds_next: std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
    -- output register keep output constant during conversion
    signal bcds_out_reg, bcds_out_reg_next: std_logic_vector(19 downto 0);
    -- need to keep track of shifts
    signal shift_counter, shift_counter_next: natural range 0 to N;
begin

    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            binary <= (others => '0');
            bcds <= (others => '0');
            state <= start;
            bcds_out_reg <= (others => '0');
            shift_counter <= 0;
        elsif falling_edge(clk) then
            binary <= binary_next;
            bcds <= bcds_next;
            state <= state_next;
            bcds_out_reg <= bcds_out_reg_next;
            shift_counter <= shift_counter_next;
        end if;
    end process;

    convert:
    process(state, binary, binary_in, bcds, bcds_reg, shift_counter)
    begin
        state_next <= state;
        bcds_next <= bcds;
        binary_next <= binary;
        shift_counter_next <= shift_counter;

        case state is
            when start =>
                state_next <= shift;
                binary_next <= binary_in;
                bcds_next <= (others => '0');
                shift_counter_next <= 0;
            when shift =>
                if shift_counter = N then
                    state_next <= done;
                else
                    binary_next <= binary(N-2 downto 0) & 'L';
                    bcds_next <= bcds_reg(18 downto 0) & binary(N-1);
                    shift_counter_next <= shift_counter + 1;
                end if;
            when done =>
                state_next <= start;
        end case;
    end process;

    bcds_reg(19 downto 16) <= bcds(19 downto 16) + 3 when bcds(19 downto 16) > 4 else
                              bcds(19 downto 16);
    bcds_reg(15 downto 12) <= bcds(15 downto 12) + 3 when bcds(15 downto 12) > 4 else
                              bcds(15 downto 12);
    bcds_reg(11 downto 8) <= bcds(11 downto 8) + 3 when bcds(11 downto 8) > 4 else
                             bcds(11 downto 8);
    bcds_reg(7 downto 4) <= bcds(7 downto 4) + 3 when bcds(7 downto 4) > 4 else
                            bcds(7 downto 4);
    bcds_reg(3 downto 0) <= bcds(3 downto 0) + 3 when bcds(3 downto 0) > 4 else
                            bcds(3 downto 0);

    bcds_out_reg_next <= bcds when state = done else
                         bcds_out_reg;

    bcd4 <= bcds_out_reg(19 downto 16);
    bcd3 <= bcds_out_reg(15 downto 12);
    bcd2 <= bcds_out_reg(11 downto 8);
    bcd1 <= bcds_out_reg(7 downto 4);
    bcd0 <= bcds_out_reg(3 downto 0);

end behaviour;
```

test bench

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY tb_bcd IS
END tb_bcd;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_bcd IS

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT binary_bcd
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         reset : IN  std_logic;
         binary_in : IN  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
         bcd0 : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd1 : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd2 : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd3 : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
         bcd4 : OUT  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal reset : std_logic := '0';
   signal binary_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --Outputs
   signal bcd0 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal bcd1 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal bcd2 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal bcd3 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   signal bcd4 : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: binary_bcd PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          reset => reset,
          binary_in => binary_in,
          bcd0 => bcd0,
          bcd1 => bcd1,
          bcd2 => bcd2,
          bcd3 => bcd3,
          bcd4 => bcd4
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin
      -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
        reset <= '1';
      wait for 100 ns;
        reset <= '0';

        binary_in <= "0000000000001111";
      wait for 200 ns;

        binary_in <= "0000000001001111";
      wait for 200 ns;

        binary_in <= "0000000001111111";
      wait for 200 ns;

        binary_in <= "0000111101001111";
      wait for 2000 ns;

    end process;

END;
```

Comment: Your question seems a bit vague, lacking context. If this is on your [DE2 board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789592/synchronous-communication-link-using-vhdl) there's a section entitled **Using the 7-segment Displays** in your user manual, noting the common cathode and anodes are pulled low to turn on. It talks about board jumpers and pin numbers. You'd need to do BCD to 7-segment conversion.

Comment: how can i do the bcd to 7segment  conversion?

Comment: I don't get it. In your last "question" you posted some code, without real question. This code contained bcd to 7segment conversion. And here you are asking for it. How does it makes sense?

Comment: There are other ways besides a separate entity/architecture pair to convert. BCD values are a subset of HEX values. See [Hex to 7 Segment Encoder Syntax Errors with When Statments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151539/hex-to-7-segment-encoder-syntax-errors-with-when-statments/33159062#33159062) where there is a ROM and function shown that can be pared down for BCD values, in addition to the selected signal assignment in your other question's BCD_TO_7SEG.

Comment: the code take the 16 bit binary and converts it into 5 BCDs. i want to splay the number in the 7segment displays. To do that from what i know i have to add some extra thing on the code so that it will connect BCD(0) to 7SEG (0) , BCD (1) to  7SEG (1), etc. but i dont know how to connect it. i have to add the following cote and some more staff

Comment: with BCD_IN select SEG_OUT <=  
           "0111111" when  "0000", 
            "0000110" when  "0001",
            "1011011" when  "0010",
            "1001111" when  "0011", 
            "1100110" when  "0100", 
            "1101101" when  "0101",
            "1111101" when  "0110", 
            "0000111" when  "0111", 
            "1111111" when  "1000", 
            "1100111" when  "1001", 
            "1111001" when others;

Comment: The model is [Get answers to practical, detailed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). In exchange for an answer there's an expectation your [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question and it's accepted answer standing alone will have value as a search reference in lieu of asking again. Your question doesn't show any displays, it's not specific or detailed. Your question doesn't specify you're using a DE2 board which has individual FPGA display segment pins shown in it's user manual but not referenced in your code. What displays? All you show is BCD digits.

Comment: Moreover, in you previous question you also have code for what you ask. I have a feeling, that this account is used by more than one person.